# Is the infinite sum $\sum_{s=2}^\infty \frac{\zeta(s)}{s!}$ known? If so, what is its value?

Tags: sequences-and-series, zeta-functions

I recently ran into this infinite sum:

$$\sum_{s=2}^\infty \frac{\zeta(s)}{s!}$$

and have tried to solve it to no avail. Any references, solutions, or general advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $\zeta_s = \zeta(s)$? $$\sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{\zeta(s)}{s!} = \sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{s!n^s} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{(1/n)^s}{s!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(e^{1/n}-1-\dfrac1n\right)$$

Comment: I wonder whether the OP meant $\,\zeta_s\,$ to be a primitive roots of unity of order $\,s\,$ ...But I really don't think so.

Comment: Sorry, in my field the standard notation for $\zeta(s)$ is $\zeta_s$. I forgot that it is not the standard notation in mathematics.

Comment: It appears at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) (equation $(133)$ and following) and [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A093720) but the initial expression (eventually rewritten as $\ \displaystyle e-2+\sum_{s=2}^\infty\frac{\zeta(s)-1}{s!}\ $) has better convergence.

Comment: @Marvis: I got your sum by a completely roundabout way, the likes of which I am now too ashamed to advertise further.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a roundabout way of linking the series to the form provided in user17762's comment, but still I'll post it.

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$$

Interchanging summation and integration we have:

$$S=\sum_{s=2}^\infty \frac{\zeta(s)}{s!}=\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{e^x-1} \sum_{s=2}^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{s!(s-1)!}$$

Now the series inside can be easily seen as:

$$\sum_{s=2}^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{s!(s-1)!}=\sum_{s=2}^\infty \frac{sx^{s-1}}{s!^2}=\frac{d}{dx} \left( I_0 (2\sqrt{x})-1-x \right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}  I_1 (2\sqrt{x})-1$$

Now we write:

> $$S=\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{e^x-1}  \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}  I_1 (2\sqrt{x})-1\right)$$

This integral is present in the MathWorld refernece from Raymond Manzoni's comment.

Let's expand:

$$\frac{1}{e^x-1} =\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-(k+1)x}$$

So:

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \int_0^\infty \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}  I_1 (2\sqrt{x})-1\right) e^{-(k+1)x}  dx=$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}  I_1 (2\sqrt{x})e^{-(k+1)x}  dx-\frac{1}{k+1} \right)$$

It can be seen using (for example) the integral definition of the Bessel function that:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}  I_1 (2\sqrt{x})e^{-(k+1)x}  dx=2 \int_0^\infty I_1 (2y)e^{-(k+1)y^2}  dy=e^{1/(k+1)}-1$$

Finally we obtain:

> $$S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( e^{1/(k+1)}-1-\frac{1}{k+1} \right)$$

Just as user17762 derived from the series definition for the Zeta function.